# Visual C++ assert- String subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

My program is a solution for the [Day 6 question in Advent of Code 2015](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/6). I get an error when I use "Start Without Debugging" and enter the [puzzle input](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/6/input) in the output window.[The image contains the exact error I received.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXzA.jpg) The error is related to "string subscript out of range". I would like help in resolving this error.

```
const int r = 1000;//global variable
const int c = 1000;//global variable
int lights[r][c];//global array

void instruction(string inp)//extracting OFF, ON, or toggle indication from the instruction
{
    int* loc;
    int coord[4] = { 0 };
    char cond = inp[7];
    loc = &coord[3];

    switch (cond)
    {
    case 'f':
        coordinates(loc, inp);
        execute(coord, cond);
        break;
    case 'n':
        coordinates(loc, inp);
        execute(coord, cond);
        break;
    default:
        coordinates(loc, inp);
        execute(coord, cond);
        break;
    }
}

void coordinates(int* loc, string inp)//extracting coordinates from the instruction
{
    int i, k = 0, l;
    l = inp.length()-1;
    for (i = l; inp[i] != ','; i--)
    {
        *loc += (inp[i]-'0') * pow(10,k);
        k++;
    }
    i--;
    loc--;
    k = 0;
    for (; inp[i] != ' '; i--)
    {
        *loc += (inp[i]-'0') * pow(10,k);
        k++;
    }
    i = i - 9;
    loc--;
    k = 0;
    for (; inp[i] != ','; i--)
    {
        *loc += (inp[i]-'0') * pow(10,k);
        k++;
    }
    i--;
    loc--;
    k = 0;
    for (; inp[i] != ' '; i--)
    {
        *loc += (inp[i]-'0') * pow(10,k);
        k++;
    }
}

void execute(int coord[], char cond)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = coord[0]; i <= coord[2]; i++)
    {
        for (j = coord[1]; j <= coord[3]; j++)
        {
            if (cond == 'f')
                lights[i][j] &= 0;
            else if (cond == 'n')
                lights[i][j] |= 1;
            else
                lights[i][j] = ~lights[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, count = 0;
    string inp;

    for (i = 0;;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter an instruction" << endl;
        cin >> inp;

        if (inp != "xx")//To manually move to counting the number of lights turned ON
            instruction(inp);
        else
        {
            for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                {
                    if (lights[j][k])
                        count++;
                }
            }
            cout << endl << "Number of lights lit " << count;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program in the debugger. Which line gives the error? What's the value of the index and the size of the vector?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely this loop (from the `coordinates` function):

```
l = inp.length()-1;
for (i = l; inp[i] != ','; i--)
{
    *loc += int(inp[i]) * (10 ^ k);
    k++;
}
```

In the very first iteration of the loop then `i` will be equal to `l` which is the length of the string, which is out of bounds.

You also don't check if you go out of bounds in the second direction (`i` becomes negative). You have this problem in all your loops in the `coordinates` function.

---

On another note, casting a character to `int` will not convert a digit character to its corresponding integer value.

Assuming ASCII encoding (the most common encoding available) then the character `'2'` (for example) will have the integer value `50`.

Also the `^` operator it bitwise [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), not any kind of "power" or "raises" operator. It seems you could need to spend some more times with some of the basics of C++.

Comment: I've ensured that `l` is reduced by 1 while initializing it.

Thank you for your comments on type casting and the exclusive OR operator. I'm just getting back to coding after a break and will surely spend more time on the basics as suggested.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Hi Barrnet Chou, I'm yet to re-check the coordinates function for errors. I shall update the post as soon as that is done. Rest assured I won't leave it open once it is solved.